# warning that sbt shell syntax is deprecated

Tags: scala, sbt

[warn] sbt 0.13 shell syntax is deprecated; use slash syntax instead: Test / package

I am getting the warning above, but I am baffled because I think I *am* using slash syntax. My build.sbt file is copied below for anyone who can tell me where I am using 0.13 shell syntax. Also, if anything else looks funny about my build.sbt file, please don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks.

```
name := "trajspec"
version := "0.999"
scalaVersion := "3.3.0"
organization := "gov.nasa.arc"
outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)
run/connectInput := true
crossPaths := false
fork := true

//run / javaOptions += "-Xprof"

Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value/"src"/"plot"
Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value/"src"/"sim"
Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value/"src"/"scalar"

Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"main"
Compile / javaSource  := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"main"
Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"scalar"
Test / scalaSource    := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"test"
Test / scalaSource    := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"plot"
Test / scalaSource    := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"sim"
Test / javaSource     := baseDirectory.value/"src"/"test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "1.0.3"

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
//scalacOptions += "-Xcheckinit"
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

Comment: Do you see this when importing to IntelliJ? Because IntelliJ sbt-plugin, which IJ injects, is called by IJ with deprecated syntax. Then you always get the warning during project importing/refreshing

Comment: No, I am not using IntelliJ, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: When do you get that warning? You only have that sbt file? Maybe another ones in `project` directory? [Migrating to slash syntax](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+to+slash+syntax) is not only for `build.sbt` files, it's also for terminal. Could be that you executed a command using the old syntax? The warning message is just that and it doesn't show something like the line number?

Comment: The warning message shows no line number. I am running it using a small bash file containing the lines "sbt package" and "sbt test:package". Only the latter triggers the warning message.

Comment: And it's the outdated syntax. It should be `sbt Test/package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Mateusz Kubuszok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305121/mateusz-kubuszok) said in the comments.

The command you are running

```scala
sbt test:package
```

is using the old and deprecated syntax.

Just changing it to

```scala
Test / package
```

will stop showing the warning

---

You have a doc that shows how to [Migrate to slash syntax](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+to+slash+syntax) in sbt 1.x

> ##### Migrating to slash syntax
>
> In sbt 0.13 keys were scoped with 2 different syntaxes: one for sbt’s shell and one for in code.
>
> - sbt 0.13 shell: `<project-id>/config:intask::key`
> - sbt 0.13 code: `key in (<project-id>, Config, intask)`
>
> Starting sbt 1.1.0, the syntax for scoping keys has been unified for both the shell and the build definitions to the slash syntax as follows:
>
> - `<project-id> / Config / intask / key`